# Visual Studio - Add default Project dependency to new projects

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, solution

I have a solution having quite a few projects and all of them need to have a specific project added as a dependency. This can be done manually, but leaves a window of error where someone might forget to do so while adding a new project to the solution (even though the newly added project may not be using a direct code reference of this common project, so compiler won't be of much help here) or, maybe have some kind of a pre-build verification script at solution level which verifies this (doesn't sound elegant to me). So I thought it would be better to let Visual Studio add a dependency to this common project by default, every time a new project is added to the solution.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Solution Explorer, select a project.
On the Project menu, choose Project Dependencies. ...
On the Dependencies tab, select a project from the Project drop-down menu.
In the Depends on field, select the check box of any other project that must build before this project does.

And the dependencies automatically gets added to a project when you create a venv(a virtual environment) to that certain project. Update Venv Path Settings in VSCode. Open VSCode preferences ( Ctrl + , ) and search for “venv”. Add ~/.virtualenvs to the “Venv Path” settings, like so: ...
Add the Virtual Environment Folder to VSCode. Add the folder that contains the virtual environment to VSCode, in our case, it is the ~/. virtualenv folder.

I hope i helped you and if i did not, then add a comment!